Как обновить baml (xaml) файл в сборке dll
У меня есть на руках dll с формами WPF (исходников нет). Одна из форм требует исправления в файле ресурсов baml (xaml).

Использую dnSpy для декомпиляции. Он позволяет менять файлы .cs через пкм Edit Class:

Для файлов ресурсов эта опция недоступна:

Есть ли способ обновить/подменить файл ресурсов сразу в dll?
Сейчас для изменения формы я декомпилирую часть сборки, создаю альтернативные классы, компилирую новую dll, а затем в необходимых местах оригинальной сборки подменяю оригинальные классы на альтернативные. Этот процесс чреват побочными ошибками, особенно если проект старый и зависимости находятся в форме вермешели. Потому ищу более элегантный способ изменения файлов ресурсов.
